# Unable to locate button that has no ID; Button has a hidden attribute value

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# with Selenium Web Driver. Issue is that I am unable to locate a start button that has no ID value.

The only unique identifier that I have found for this object is the 'value="74"' text.

HTML for the button is as follows:

```
<div class="product-item-inner">
  <div class="product">
     <h3>Cyber Liability</h3>
     <p class="carrier-about">Lloyd's, London - AM BEST "A" (Excellent)</p>
  </div>
 <form action="/index.php?c=pcs.integrate" method="POST">
    <input value="74" name="product_id" type="hidden">
    <input value="" name="insured_id" type="hidden">
    <input value="" name="contract_class_id" type="hidden">
    <a href="#" class="product-information">Product Information</a>

    <a class="tile-button start" href="#">Start</a>
 </form> 
</div>
```

I was able to perform a record and playback using Firefox IDE (see line below) but I need a way to consistently locate the button object using a unique identifier.

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Start')])[16]")).Click();

I have tried the following but it is not working:

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//input[@name='product_id'][@value='74'])")).Click();

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clicking on the **'Start' button with respect to the text 'Cyber Liability'** above, you can try the below xpath:

```
//h3[.='Cyber Liability']/ancestor::div[@class='product-item-inner']//a[.='Start']
```

This will locate the `a` element with innerHTML/text as `Start` which is a descendant node of `div` element with `class` attribute as `product-item-inner` which is the ancestor of `h3` element with innerHTML/text as `Cyber Liability`.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please accept  this answer too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click on a hidden element. If yu want to find the start link right next to the hidden element you can do it like this:

```
//a[..\input[@name='product_id'][@value='74']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important attribute of the  element is the href attribute, which indicates the link's destination. You can use it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Start")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CssSelector to locate start button.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".tile-button.start")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution from Subh worked.

//h3[.='Cyber Liability']/ancestor::div[@class='product-item-inner']//a[.='Start']